# Python Pandas- remove rows based on given value

Tags: python, pandas

I think I am close but following error show up: Could you advice what is the reason?

> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'DATE OF OPERATION'

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
source_files = sorted(Path(r'/Users/user/Downloads/').glob('*.csv'))

for file in source_files:
 df = pd.read_csv(file)
 #df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
 df = df[~df['DATE OF OPERATION'].astype(str).str.startswith('202110')]
 #df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')
 name, ext = file.name.split('.')
 df.to_csv(f'{name}.{ext}', index=0)
```

error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'DATE OF OPERATION'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ShareOpe/ShareOpe.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = df.loc[~df['DATE OF OPERATION'].astype(str).str.startswith('202110')]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'DATE OF OPERATION'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @eshirvana would you be able to assist with above error? thanks a lot!

Comment: provide sample file , so I can reproduce the issue. but the error message bascially is saying it can't find column 'DATE OF OPERATION'

Comment: Apparently I can't attach csv file here, so I've added picture of the table. As you can see I have a column with header DATE OF OPERATION. No idea why it can't be recognised as colum. Your input would be very helpful - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to remove rows you can use `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[~df['DATE OF OPERATION'].str.startswith('202110')]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I received error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'. So I replaced startswith with str.startswith but then the error: KeyError: 'DATE OF OPERATION' is back.

Comment: @user14566555 is that the full error message?

Comment: Error message is too long for comment so I pasted it below in answer

Comment: @user14566555 edit your question adn add it to your question and remove it from answer section

Comment: Do you think the error appears because DATE OF OPERATION is not recognised as excel column for some reason? Is there way to make sure that python recognise it as column header?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Pandas Article](https://www.statology.org/pandas-drop-rows-with-value/) from may 14 2021.

```
#drop rows that contain specific 'value' in 'column_name'
df = df[df.your_column_name != value_to_remove]
```